# My video couldn't play with MPMoviePlayer?xcode

Tags: xcode, video

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *movieFile1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"mp4"];
    self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile1]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I turned this video to mp4,mov,3gp,m4v ,but always:

Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Please help me!

I think it should the problem of format .Because when I use the video from support.apple.com
,this code works. So what should I do?

Comment: Try move `[super viewDidLoad];` to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this as [super viewDidLoad]; to the top:

```
NSString *movieFile1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"mp4"];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:movieFile1])// check whether file exists
{
  self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile1]];
  if(self.moviePlayer) //reference of movie player created
  {
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds]; 
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
  }
}
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController did show on your screen.Also debug code

Comment: I found the problem,I didn't copy the video into folder!Thank you

Comment: so file doesnot exits in apps